# Question about process injection

Tags: assembly, malware, injection

During an analysis, I found the following piece of malware:

```
   ...
   lea eax, [ebp+ThreadId]
   push eax                   ;lpThreadId
   push ebx                   ;dwCreationFlags
   push [ebp+lpParameter]     ;lpParameter
   push [ebp+lpStartAddress]  ;lpStartAddress
   push ebx                   ;dwStackSize
   push ebx                   ;lpThreadAttributes
   push [ebp+hProcess]        ;hProcess
   call CreateRemoteThread
   ...
```

### What I definitely know

From some previous parts, I know that

```
xor ebx, ebx -> ebx = NULL or zero
```

At the address pointed to by `lpParameter`, the malware stores the address of `LoadLibrary`. And `hProcess` is a handle to `explorer.exe`.

### What I want to know

Related to `lpStartAddress`, I have found the following lines:

```
  ...
  push ebx
  push [ebp+nSize]
  push offset loc_402B58
  push [ebp+lpStartAddress]
  push [ebp+hProcess] 
  call WriteProcessMemory
  ...
```

So, this function writes the content of `offset loc_402B58` into the region of pages started at `lpStartAddress` (which was allocated some lines before).
Now, when I go to `offset loc_402B58`, I see the following (note: I use IDA PRO):

```
loc_402B58:
 push esi
 mov esi, [esp+8]
 lea eax, [esi+14h]
 push eax
 call dword ptr[esi]
 test eax, eax
 mov [esi+10h], eax
 jz short loc_402B80
 lea ecx, [esi+46h]
 push ecx
 push eax
 call dword ptr [esi+4]
 test eax, eax
 jz short_loc402B80
 call eax
 push 0
 call eax                  <----- edited because i have forgotten it
 push 0                    <-----                    ''
 call dword ptr [esi+8]    <-----                    ''

loc_402B80:     
 xor eax, eax
 pop esi
 retn 4
```

So my question would be:

> What does the assembly at `loc_402B58` and `loc_402B80` ?

Comment: Can not be said with the limited information given. As you see loc_402B58 access esp+8 which is the parameter given in the CreateRemoteTHread call. So without knowledge of that there is no way of knowing

Comment: the parameter given to CreateRemoteThread is the address of the function "LoadLibrary", as I wrote. Or, how can I look which information is at esp+8 ?

Comment: Yes, however I am not sure whether it's only that. Consider line 5 `call [esi]` which is the call to LoadLibrary(). However on line 3 it accesses the parameter + 0x14 and uses that as the DLL name that is passed to LoadLibrary.

Answer (score 1):

It should also be storing address of `GetProcAddress() at <lpparm+4>`

it should store a string the `name of module at <lpparam+14>`

it should store a string the `name of proc for getProcAddress at <lpparm+46>`

at `[esp+8]` it accesses the lpparam which was written to the remote process so you may need to find this `WriteProcessMemory Also` and look at the `local Buffer to Know the data` ie name of dll and name of Proc

or you may need to attach to the Remote process and `Break on Thread CreateEvent` and single Step through the `BaseThreadStartThunk()`  Routine  in this routine you will notice ebp is Zeored in there and Eax and Ebx holds LpStart and lpParam and that is how lpStart gets Executed

```
push [ebp+c] lpparam
call [enp+8] lpStart
```

esi gets the lpparm via mov esi [esp+8] which in your case holds the Address of LoadLibrary as you correctly observed but you have not observed what is at

```
assuming [esp+8 ] holds 403000 <lpparam>
[[esp+8] + 0 ] [403000] holds Address of LoadLibrary as you observed
[[esp+8] + 4]  [403004] will hold Address of GetProcAddress
[[esp+8] + 14] [403014] will hold a string the dll name
[[esp+8] + 46] [403046] will hold the name of  Proc in the Loaded Dll
[[esp+8] + 10] [403010] gets the Result of LoadLibrary Return in your above snippet
```

**edit**

added the annotated snippet for referance

```
push esi
 mov esi, [esp+8]    <lpparameter> assuming 403000
 lea eax, [esi+14h]  lpparameter+14> should be a string the name of dll 403014
 push eax            push 403014    
 call dword ptr[esi] DWORD [ lpparmeter+0 ] = [403000] = Address Of LoadLib so calling loadlib
 test eax, eax
 mov [esi+10h], eax  [lpparam+10] [403010] store LoadLibResult here
 jz short loc_402B80  failure
 lea ecx, [esi+46h] [403046] = <lpparm+46> again a string name of Proc for GetProcAddress()
 push ecx           processname     
 push eax           HandletoLoadedmod  
 call dword ptr [esi+4]  Must be Address of GetProcAddress from the looks check your code 
capture local buffer when Writing to ProcessMemory or Break on Create new Thread in the RemoteProcess
by attaching a debugger Executing the RemoteDebugge and when a new Thread Create Event is triggered 
single step to find the contents of lpparam
 test eax, eax    
 jz short_loc402B80
 call eax  <calls the  functions that was just getproc'ed>
 push 0
 call
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helps a lot. I complete the lines after the last call instruction because I have forgotten it. So, what the code construct does is to get a handle to a dll and use that handle later for GetProcAddress to retrieve the address of a process from that dll. Okay.

Comment: nitpick not process but proc -------------------------------The term Proc Literally Denotes a Function Address in a Process Space where Process is Term that Denotes a Collection Of threads that are Scheduleable to Execute in a Processor